# PHPSESSID deletes on ios webapp

Tags: php, ios, session, web-applications, cookies

I am making a website that requires complete anonymity, but i want to send messages to that user, now I am insert the users cookie: PHPSESSID.

but I need to make it work on iPhone/iPad and if I close the webapp delete the iPhone the PHPSESSID cookie, so any suggestions to make it work that the cookie will not be changed or any alternatives?

Comment: You are probably looking for something called [*Evercookie*](http://samy.pl/evercookie/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard PHP behaviour is to let the session cookie expire once the browser closes. See this related question: [How do I create persistent sessions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797913/how-do-i-create-persistent-sessions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should check your browser's settings about cookies, take a look at [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta38619), this may help you.