# Why can't I set PHP $_SESSION from a whatwg-fetch request?

Tags: php, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a simple fetch request that looks like this:

## JavaScript (React)

```
fetch('/includes/signon.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    Email: event.target.form.email.value,
    Password: event.target.form.password.value,
  })
})
.then((response) => {
  return response.text()
}).then((body) => {
  this.displayWelcomeMessage(body);
})
```

And on the backend, I have PHP that handles the fetch request like so:

## PHP 5

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');
session_start();

$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($request_body);

if (!empty($json->Email) && !empty($json->Password)) {
  global $db, $json;
  $sql = "SELECT `user_id` from users where email = ? AND password = ?;";
  $stmt = $db->initialize_statement();
  if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $error = $stmt->error;
    echo $stmt->error;
  } else {
    $email = $json->Email;
    $password = $json->Password; // Stored as a string for the sake of simplicity
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      if ($stmt->num_rows === 0) {
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
      } else {
        // Here lies the problem...
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result;
        echo "Welcome, User #".$result."!";
      }
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
} else {
  var_dump($_SESSION); // For debugging purposes only
}
```

Now, here's the problem! The body of the response displays "Welcome, User #12!" when I log in like it should, but `$_SESSION['user_id']` is set to `12` without being stored in the actual session...

If I make a GET request to the page, it dumps the `$_SESSION` out and `$_SESSION['user_id']` is nowhere to be found.

Why? What am I doing wrong? I just want to finish this project...

**UPDATE:** The `var_dump($_SESSION);` at the bottom of the page is dumping a different session than the `$_SESSION` that I'm using to store `"user_id"`. I wonder what is causing this? Why would it dump a different session than the one I'm storing variables in?

`session_id()` on session I'm storing to: `0q44kc1fkph8fkc8gt35gfabe6`

`session_id()` on session I'm dumping: `a493j3v5vbnlon02s1s7bpkqj3`

So... It's creating a new session every time I set `"user_id"`? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue most likely lies in the fact that you have cookies enabled for sessions, and the cookie lifetime is 0. For example, let's try making it 7 days instead at the beginning of your script:

`ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);`

If this works, I would recommend moving the `session.cookie_lifetime` setting to your `php.ini` file so each script you write does not require running `ini_set()`.

For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797962/823549

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. For some reason, I'm looking in my php.ini file and inside the directory found at session.save_path and I'm finding that it's creating two files **and one is empty.** I wonder if that could be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: No problem. I have a feeling this may be because you are posting via React to your endpoint, the session is getting created, but not then attributed to the actual frontend.

Comment: ^ I think you're right about that. I'm looking into the PHP docs right now (specifically here:[www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) to see if I can figure out a way to get my script to keep track of the session ID (possibly storing it in the database or something).

Comment: I wonder if when the session starts and it assigns a cookie, you need to actually receive that cookie in React and assign it to the user's browser?

Comment: Like as in JavaScript localStorage or something along those lines? docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I haven't used much ReactJS before, but potentially https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie?

Comment: Ooh... I will look into react-cookie. I'm not set up to do development right now though... I will have to get back to you when I get it running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165348/discussion-between-1000nettles-and-ihodonald).