# How to save steam login session?

Tags: steam-web-api

Im trying to make a steam login on my website.

I used [this](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/) steam login, it works fine but the only problem is that after sometime my session expires and I need to log in again. On the sites I've been on it could be weeks and the session wouldn't expire. I think I could do it using cookies but I don't know how.

I've searched on the internet solutions but ended up getting nothing so I'm here.

Comment: Can you check your `php.ini` for the value of `session.cookie_lifetime`? It's possible you need to specify a longer time for your session cookies to last.

Comment: It's on `0` right now, how much should I put it on? For example to last for a week. 604800 ?

Comment: A value of `0` means the cookies sticks around until you close your browser. Try setting it to 24 hours by setting it to `86400`. The value is represented [in seconds](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime). Alternatively, you could use [ini_set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797962/9882907) at the start of your file if you don't want to change the setting globally.

Comment: @Worthwelle Yes, It's displaying that the cookie will expire in a week. Shouldn't I change any other values like `session.gc_maxlifetim` or something?

Answer (score 2):

You should change the value of `session.cookie_lifetime` to a number in `seconds` in the `php.ini` file you're using. For example, if you're using `PHP 5.6 fpm` you should go to the directory of the php 5.6 fpm, for me it's `/etc/php/5.6/fpm` there's a `php.ini` file, change it and then go to the terminal and write there `/etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm restart` to restart the service. Refresh the website and it should be working.