# How to increase session value for 1 day in php ? Like Facebook and Gmail.

Tags: php, session

I have created one simple website for my client. Using Register and Login form with the session.

I want to maintain session after closing the browser, shut down the computer and reopen website after the 1 day. (No need to re-login).

I have already used below code for that but still not getting success.

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID',session_id(),60*60*24);
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 7200
session.gc_maxlifetime=315360000
session.use_cookies=1
session.cookie_lifetime=315360000
```

Please guide me if any wrong from my side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create persistent sessions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797913/how-do-i-create-persistent-sessions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Setcookie expire argument is not a time value, it's a Unix value.
As you written the cookie should expire January 2 1970.
What you should do is use `time()+60*60*24` if you want one day cookie lifetime.

Comment: Thank you. :)
It is working fine.
setcookie('PHPSESSID',session_id(),time()+60*60*24);
I did checked with setcookie('PHPSESSID',session_id(),time()+60); // For 1 mint. and it is working fine.