# Session Expires, Logs User Out, Before I Tell It To

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables, session-state

I want my users to be logged in for a period of one week without having to log back in again. I implemented the solution on this page [How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php) but it is not working. I still get logged out after a period of inactivity (not sure how long, but often, at least a few times a day).

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 604800);
session_set_cookie_params(604800);
ob_start(); 
session_start();
$now = time();
if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after']) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['discard_after'] = $now + 604800;
```

Comment: Isn't this helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797913/how-do-i-create-persistent-sessions-in-php

Comment: @EliâMelfior - Well, I think what that article is saying is to set the cookie lifetime, but I am pretty sure that is what this line of code is doing... session_set_cookie_params(604800)

Comment: Just in the time since I wrote this until now I went back to the site and was logged out.